# Get Report parameter values

Tags: reporting-services

I have a button on my reports page to create a report subscription. I'm using the report viewer control to get the values for the report parameters and to give the users the option of viewing the report in browser.

I need to somehow get the selected values to pass it to the `CreateSubscription` call. This happens on my button click event.

The `SubmittingParameterValues` event is only fired on the click of 'View Report'.